# could not start with Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new in Angular. Here I am trying to create a new web application in Angular 8 I got this error:

````
   .....................etc............
     CREATE my-dream/e2e/protractor.conf.js (810 bytes)
      CREATE my-dream/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
       CREATE my-dream/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (637 bytes)
      CREATE my-dream/e2e/src/app.po.ts (251 bytes)
npm ERR! cb() never called!
    npm ERR! cb() never called!
    npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-12T09_30_50_474Z-debug.log
    Package install failed, see above.

I also installed npm`s latest version and started cmd using these commands:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-dream-app
cd my-dream-app 
```
````

Comment: First, try to update your "npm" version and then try "ng new appName"

Comment: what are you nodejs and npm versions?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo 6.10.3

Comment: Try installing 
Nodejs LTS version and latest npm version and then run your commands

Comment: Try installing the latest node version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest Nodejs installed

**Step 1:** run `npm install -g npm`

**Step 2:** run `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-12T09_30_50_474Z-debug.log

Delete this and run the command in cmd ng serve --open